# How do you convert a string to a function in python?

Tags: python

How do you convert a string (for example, input from a textbox) into a proper function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `eval`. But be very careful! This opens up lots of security holes.

```
>>> s = '3+4'
>>> eval(s)
7
```

If you want it callable:

```
>>> s = '3+4'
>>> f = eval('lambda: ' + s)
>>> f()
7
```

More information on `eval` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
func = ___import___('func_name')
```

or

```
if hasattr(your_module, func_name): func = getattr(your_module, func_name)
```

or

```
if func_name in globals(): func = globals[func_name]
```

or something etc

Answer (score 0):

```
def func():
    print "hello"

# just eval it
eval(raw_input())

# if you just want to ask for name
fName=raw_input()
if fName in globals():
    globals()[fName]()
```

And there could be various other ways depending on what is the objective?

Comment: hi anurag, just for a little beginner experiment - get the user to type a function and then i graph it

Comment: in that case I think eval would be just fine, you can use pycallgraph.start_trace() (http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com) before eval